# Do I need to Unsubscribe Router's event observable

Tags: angular

I have confusion with Angular docs statement, which says "This means all the component's members will also be destroyed"

[Doc Link](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse)

so the question is do i need to unsubscribe it or not,

```
  constructor(
    private readonly router: Router
  ) {
      this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
```

It clearly says about `ActivatedRoute` need not to be unsubscribed, but keeps the confusion for `Router` observable like `events`.

Comment: The things is... do you WANT to unsubscribe? It doesn't complete after first emit of an event. So it keeps emitting events. Do you want/need to listen to the stream or only need 1 value? It is up to you 

Comment: So it means it keeps the memory leak in place even if i navigated away from the component where i wrote the code at.

Comment: It's a good idea to do it regardless, plus it can't hurt. The potential issue is that you subscribe, navigate away, come back to this page and now there are multiple subscriptions for the same thing.

Comment: At component destroy life cycle event all subscriptions should be unsubscribed off course.

Answer (score 2):

It is talking about `ActivatedRoute` but not `Router`the solution would be to do

```
eventSubscription:Subscription;

...

this.eventSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {

...

ngOnDestroy () {

  this.eventSubscription.unsubscribe()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to usubscribe from Router events because `Router` is global reusable provider, so even after the component destroy `Router` will be living in DI with all subcriptions.